# Bootstrap layout with different card heights is breaking on some resolutions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been working on a Bootstrap layout that has regular thumbnails and featured ones. I have one big featured thumb at the beginning which works ok, but the second one that is floated to right, on some resolutions breaks the layout.

Is there anything I can do to make it not break the layout? From what I've observed, the featured thumb doesn't have the same height as two rows of regular thumbs plus the space between them.

Here's the layout:

HTML

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.row [class*=col-] {
  padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
         <img src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/jackpotGameThumbs/ISBKobushi.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-11/G170191.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img class="thumb" src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-3/PGBookOfDead.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img class="thumb" src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-6/BSFruitZen.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img class="thumb" src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-6/BSBoomanji.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img class="thumb" src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-11/G170191.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img class="thumb" src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-3/PGBookOfDead.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img class="thumb"src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-6/BSFruitZen.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img class="thumb" src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-6/BSBoomanji.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-11/G170191.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <img class="thumb" src="https://d1i6itcsqouwzx.cloudfront.net/cms/images/games/provider-id-3/PGBookOfDead.jpg">
      </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 pull-right">
```

CSS

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.row [class*=col-] {
  padding: 1%;
}
```

Comment: can you show the structure you are expecting and what you are getting

Comment: Can you please put your code using working snippet

Comment: I want the grid to have it's thumbnails close together, only the padding between them. Right now on tablet resolution, some thumbs do not align properly and big empty spaces appear after the second featured thumbnail. I want the whole grid to keep it's structure.